# Usar promise em um Web Worker

Tags: javascript, assincronismo, web-worker

To usando Web Workers para certas coisas, tem como usar uma promise para quando ele acabar de executar?

Tipo assim

```
WR.postMessage({taskID: 'g_b_i'}).then(function(nonce){
        console.log(dT(), 'Sending parameter nonce: ', nonce);
    });
```

o `nonce` seria o valor retornado pela mensagem.

Comment: Isso é javascript, mas no node.js né? Se for adicione a tag node.js a pergunta, vai ter mais chances de receber uma boa resposta para seu problema. E se não for ignore. =D

Comment: é puro JS mesmo, nao usei node.js @Fernando Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método [`WebWorker.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) não retorna nada ("Void"), de modo que ele não pode ser usado diretamente dessa forma. Se você quiser usar promessas, terá que implementar isso você mesmo.

Uma forma de fazer isso é associando a cada mensagem que você envia pro *web worker* um ID único, e ao final de toda execução o *worker* envia o resultado também acompanhado desse ID único. Então é só chamar o método `resolve` ou `reject` associado a esse ID, conforme a tarefa tenha tido sucesso ou não (isso tem de ser indicado pelo próprio *worker*, naturalmente).

Código da página principal:

```js
// Simulação de um webWorker (para testes)
var WR = {
    postMessage: function(event) {
        event = { data:event };

        var data = event.data;
        // Faz alguma coisa com data.dados
        setTimeout(function() {
            if ( Math.random() < 0.7 )
                WR.onmessage({ data:{ ok:data.msgid, dados:"dados " + data.msgid }});
            else
                WR.onmessage({ data:{ falhou:data.msgid, dados:"outrosdados " + data.msgid }});
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000));
    }
}

// Implementação
var msgseq = 1;
var callbacks = {};
function postWithPromise(WR, dados) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var id = msgseq++;
        WR.postMessage({ msgid: id, dados:dados });
        callbacks[id] = { resolve:resolve, reject:reject };
    });
}
WR.onmessage = function(event) {
    var data = event.data;
    if ( data.ok ) {
        callbacks[data.ok].resolve(data.dados);
        delete callbacks[data.ok];
    }
    if ( data.falhou ) {
        callbacks[data.falhou].reject(data.dados);
        delete callbacks[data.falhou];
    }
}

// Exemplo de uso
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
    postWithPromise(WR, "dados").then(function(dados) { 
        alert("OK (" + dados + ")");
    }, function(dados) {
        alert("Falhou (" + dados + ")");
    });
};
```

```html
<button>Testar</button>
```

Código do *worker*:

```
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    var data = event.data;

    // Faz alguma coisa com data.dados

    if ( Math.random() < 0.7 )
        self.postMessage({ ok:data.msgid, dados:"dados " + data.msgid });
    else
        self.postMessage({ falhou:data.msgid, dados:"outrosdados " + data.msgid });
}
```

Para um exemplo funcional, usar esse [fragmento de] HTML ["teste.html"](http://pastebin.com/DsCY8Fuf) e esse código JavaScript ["worker.js"](http://pastebin.com/1PQigDLq). Nota: é preciso um *webserver* para o exemplo funcionar, não se pode carregar um *worker* a partir do `file:///` (no Chrome, pelo menos).

Comment: Nao entendi o uso do setinterval..

Comment: @user3163662 Eu não posso criar um exemplo no Stack Snippets (ou mesmo no jsFiddle) com um *web worker* de verdade, pois precisaria de um arquivo .js externo, então eu "simulei" um *web worker* usando `setTimeout` (é pra resposta chegar de forma assíncrona, tal como seria num uso real). No *web worker* real, o `setTimeout` é desnecessário.

Comment: Eu fiz uma "gambiarra" passando o codigo que deveria ser executado no final em forma de string e a executando depois no "onmessage"

Comment: Tentei de toda forma usar seu código mas nao consigo entende-lo, consegue clarificar usando codigo real? Nao precisa funcionar aqui, é só pra eu entender mesmo

Comment: @user3163662 Mexi um pouco no código pra ficar mais parecido com o código real (os eventos do *web worker* passam os dados numa propriedade `data`, não direto no evento) e coloquei dois arquivos no pastebin com um exemplo funcional (testei aqui, no Chrome, e parece tudo ok).

Comment: consegui entender melhor, é bastante funcional, Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível, como não há menção qualquer sobre promises na [API de WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker).

O worker não tem nada de promise implementado e não é um processamento assíncrono como ajax. É possível conversar com ele apenas através de mensagens.

Comment: Na realidade ele *é* um processamento assíncrono como ajax... O restante da resposta está correto, entretanto.

Comment: Assíncrono, sim, mas não como ajax. WebWorker é um "processo paralelo" para o navegador, o assíncrono comum é executado em "threads" pelo interpretador.